# Fancybox - Disable close on outside click

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-3

I'm trying to prevent close of fancybox when someone click outside of `fancybox-content` area.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="banner-message" style="display: none">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery.fancybox.open(jQuery('#banner-message'), {
    clickOutside: false
});
```

**DEMO:**
https://jsfiddle.net/xjw4b5jq/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `clickSlide` option instead.

fancybox3 works as a slider and you can reposition/resize slider area, therefore there are two similar, but different options.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this config to prevent closing the modal clicking outside.

```
<!--HTML-->

<a id="enlace" href="#modal">enlace</a>

<div id="modal">
   <p>Hola cracks</p>
</div>


// script

$("#enlace").fancybox({
   clickSlide: false,
   clickOutside: false
});
```

hope it works for u too :)